# How to Man-in-the-middle a whole network?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, wireless, data-leakage

When performing a MiTM attack, you generally need to specify the router's IP address and the "victim" IP address.

I'm trying to demonstrate to a business owner why he needs to secure his network, but he says since I can't 'capture enough data to be useful' he sees no reason to put a simple password on his router.

Is there any way to spoof only the router's IP address, redirecting all traffic through you?

I'm using Kali Linux 1.10.

Comment: You can specify the netblock as the "victim".

Comment: Not sure if this is the modern way to do things, but have you considered [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing)?

Comment: @Paul I'm using arpspoof on kali

Comment: @schroeder getting a segmentation fault when using, for example, 192.168.0.1/24 as well as 192.168.0.1-255

Comment: Please read the man page for arpspoof: `-t target Specify a particular host to ARP poison (if not specified, all hosts on the LAN).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various attacks you can demonstrate in the local network to make your point clear. You can do the classics like ARP-Spoffing, a rogue DHCP-Server or macflooding. Macflooding will cause the switch either to go into fail-open mode which basicly turns it into a hub or in fail-off which turns your MITM attempet into a DOS attack so it's kind of a risky thing to do.

In my experience in a windows network NBNS/LLMNR-Spoofing in combination with WPAD Redirection and force NTLM-Authentification is very effective (sadly it doesnt have anything to do with the switch/router but I think buissnes guy doens't know that...). There is a pretty great implementation of this attack in a tool called `Responder`. You can bringt internet explorer users send you their NTML hashes so the only thing you have to do is collect them, crack them or pth them. I consider the key to his account might be what he calles "useful data"...

Answer (score 1):

For a nice visual demonstration you can use the graphical interface of [Ettercap](https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) (`ettercap -G`) in combination with Wireshark or [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/tutorials/transparent-dhcp.html) to run several types of MiTM attacks. There are several [plugins for Ettercap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ettercap_plugins) which could help you with the demonstration.

> I'm trying to demonstrate to a business owner why he needs to secure
>   his network, but he says since I can't 'capture enough data to be
>   useful he sees no reason to put a simple password on his router.

As long the traffic is not encrypted, the password can be sniffed anyway. Beware that it's not an easy task to defend a network against MiTM attacks, just in case the demonstration was good and your customer is asking for it.

Comment: Hellreaver's problem is that he can only get the data from a single host. He's  asking how to spoof more hosts.

Comment: I didn't wanted to post RTFM. Rather I tried to show a move convenient way to solve the problem.